# firebase get all data using angular6

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
firebase.database().ref('LoginCredentials/').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot.key); 
    var data= snapshot.val().Email;

    var password =snapshot.val().Password

    console.log(data,"LoginCredentials");
    console.log(password)
});
```

My question is:
How to access variable data and password globally?

Comment: What do you mean by "globally"?

Comment: globally means any where in the component

Comment: may be this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2